# CruiseControl.Net failing with exception when trying to create VM from template

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol

I have inherited support of a product which after 2.5 years without issues is now throwing the following exception: 
"ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: Error creating VM [Unable to create VM based on [Template_VS2013]. Error: The specified key, name, or identifier 'Template_VS2013' already exists.]"

I have no direct access to the production environment but it appears that there the key and name do not actually already exist. I inherited some support documentation which states that this error is caused by lack of space on the server the code is running on but there are TBs of free disk space.

The code is C# using CruiseControl.Net

Does anyone have any insight as to what could be causing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is caused by a VMWare bug with caching: https://communities.vmware.com/thread/476449

We are working on a workaround / fix at the moment